# iOS In App Purchase requests login twice

Tags: ios, ios6, in-app-purchase

I'm adding In App Purchases to one of my apps. As required, I've added a button to let users re-download purchased items. Here is the IBAction method for that:

```
- (IBAction)touchedButtonUnlockAgain:(id)sender {
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];            
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];

}
```

When I tap this button, I get the standard login box. I enter my Sandbox username and password (correctly, verified). After that login box disappears, it reappears half a second later. So, I login again with the same username and password (correctly, verified) and THEN the purchases get re-downloaded. I have verified it happens in the Simulator and on a device (iOS 6.0 in both cases).

Why am I getting prompted for my username/password twice?

Comment: I'm having this same problem, strangely it only happens on my iPhone (6.1) and not my iPad (6.1.2), any luck?

Comment: Nope, no luck. I even published the app and it happens in the live environment in an app downloaded from the App Store.

Comment: I have the same issue, how to fix it??

Answer (score 5):

The only reason for this will be unfinished transactions - the ghosts that wait for their `finishTransaction` call for redemption. They may exist due to signed-out user initiated transactions that couldn't be finished - or simply due to abrupt app termination before they could finish. Basically, unbalanced calls to `addPayment` / `restoreCompletedTransactions` and `finishTransaction` can cause them.

Check your delegates: `paymentQueue:RestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` & `paymentQueue:restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:`

Are you doing anything twice? Do you receive any error?

One more thing to check is: When in your app life cycle do you call following statement?

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver]
```

This is important to be called as early as possible - because sometimes lost transactions that turn ghosts due to app termination appear again - expecting to be finished. Without an active observer, they don't hit updatedTransactions method which is their final gateway to `finishTransaction` call.

Comment: I believe this turned out to be a bug in iOS because I scoured the code and never found a second call... but one day, it magically stopped happening.

Comment: This answer is correct!  I asked the same question at WWDC during the StoreKit lab session this year (2015). If you don't get to ```finishTransaction``` in time during a session and then you call your transactionObserver to instantiate at this time it'll call up all transactions that didn't get to finish the previous time around.  However, they recommend you don't just call ```finishTransaction``` to remove them - you must set it up correctly. Apple thinks that users will come back to the app to finish the transaction at some point; which is why this behavior happens.

Comment: Thanks Drmorgan...I have checked this scenario - checking the transaction object pointers each time it hits updatedTransactions breakpoint -  once I call finishtransactions on those objects, I have verified that those objects no longer reappear with login box.

Answer (score -1):

On your phone, try going into Settings/iTunes & App Stores and sign out the existing Apple ID specified there.  Go back into your app and try it again.

Comment: I was already signed out. I'm signing in with my test account from within the app. This is not it, and honestly should have been a comment not an answer.